# Fisher Information with respect to the Standard deviation of Normal distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, unbiased-estimator, fisher-information

Let $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ be given. I computed the Fisher Information to be $I(\sigma)=\frac{2}{\sigma^2}$. Note that the Fisher Information for the variance is given by $I(\sigma^2)=\frac{1}{2\sigma^4}$

Furthermore, I proved that if we have $\lambda=g(\xi)$ where $g$ is bijective, that we must have for the Fisher Information $I(\lambda)$, that $I(\xi)=I(g(\xi))g'(\xi)$.

However, in the case of the normal distribution as stated above, we should have $\sigma^2=g(\sigma),\ g\colon x\mapsto x^2$ and this does not satisfy the relation I proved. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Since Fisher information is based on a second derivative, not a first derivative, are you sure that $g'$ is correct?  Note also that since you haven't actually shown us any of your math, we have little hope of pointing out where your mistake is other than through a lucky guess.

Comment: It was indeed not correct, thank you. The correct form is $I(\xi)=I(g(\xi))(g'(\xi))^2$ which then works fine.